# NSURLErrorDomain Error 1012 when logging into twitter using Parse's PFTwitterUtils on IOS

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

I can't figure out how to allow PFusers to log into Twitter. I followed the steps that parse recommended and the app keeps returning this error when I attempt to log in.

> "Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x1704618c0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token, NSUnderlyingError=0x17424d050 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)", NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token}"

I have looked at other questions posted about the 1012 error, and they said to add a callback URL on the Twitter developer page. I added one, which I am not sure what it's purpose is, and I still get the error.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. (Also I am still using Objective-C, so please use that in examples) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue myself. I have been getting 1012 when authorising Twitter when the device or simulator doesn't have any credentials set within the Twitter section within Settings.app.